# Create Jenkins slave from command line

Tags: jenkins, command-line

I have a script that create a VM then I need to add the new VM as a slave to existing master,
How can I do that from command line in windows and from the new VM ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a VM (OS = WINDOWS)

Create a Node on jenkins server from command line using [jenkins cli](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/):

```
config.xml | ssh -l fmud -p %JNLP_PORT% %jenkins_IPADDRESS% create-node %TARGET_WIN_NODE_NAME%
```

Where Config.xml could be gathered from an existing slave with command:

```
ssh -l fmud -p %JNLP_PORT% %jenkins_IPADDRESS% get-node %TARGET_WIN_NODE_NAME%
```

Note: JNLP is needed for jenkins-CLI and could be configured in jenkins administrative page.

Also, you will have to change the config file with label and name etc.

- Connect the windows slave as service: Download [winsw.exe](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/releases/download/winsw-v%7B%7B%20winsw_version%20%7D%7D/WinSW.NET4.exe)
- Rename it to jenkins_slave.exe
- Download slave.jar (http://yourserver:port/jnlpJars/agent.jar )
- Download and configure [jenkins-slave.xml](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slave-installer-module/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/modules/windows_slave_installer/jenkins-slave.xml)
- Download and configure [jenkins-slave.exe.config](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slave-installer-module/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/modules/windows_slave_installer/jenkins-slave.exe.config)
- in cmd: jenkins_slave.exe install
- jenkins_slave.exe start

If it is a java slave, that is simple to automate.  Like it if you find it helping or ask more specific question otherwise.

Comment: @Epligam: Did you try this? Was this helping ?

Comment: this was super useful